Как исправить баг с прокруткой в Boostratp 5.0.2?
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark offcanvas-navbar" style="z-index: 9990;" >
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
            data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbarDark" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbarDark" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start text-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbarDark"
         aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarDarkLabel">
        <div class="offcanvas-header bg-dark">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body bg-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active text-dark" aria-current="page" href="#project-overview">Project
                        Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#our-team">Our Team</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                                style="font-size: 13px;">Documentation
                            <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Technical Documentation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ethics & Responsibility</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Licensing & Contribution</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Проблема заключается в том, что я когда нажимаю на иконку навбара слева сверху, все открывается, но как только я начинаю закрывать его, меня перелистывает на вверх сайта и он больше не крутиться вообще. Работает некоректно, бывает открывается и дергается, а без z-index он вообще не открывается, не имею даже представления, как это как исправить.
Использую Bootstrap 5.0.2. Возможно сверстал неправильно вернюю часть сайта, и теперь какие-то стили мешают работать этому навбару, но не могу понять и найти их. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чём проблема

Вот рабочий вариант Вашего примера


<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <!-- Обязательные метатеги -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Привет мир!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="btn btn-dark" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#offcanvasExample" role="button" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
    </a>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header bg-dark">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <div>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Project Overview</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Team</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown mt-2">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-none dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Documentation
      </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Technical Documentation</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ethics & Responsibility</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Licensing & Contribution</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



Но, если есть возможность, то есть возможность, т.е. если Вы только начали верстать сайт, то рекомендую использовать более новую версию bootstrap. Хотя бы 5.1, а то и выше, там больше функционал. Вот, например, Ваша навигационная панель версии 5.1


<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <!-- Обязательные метатеги -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Привет мир!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
          <div class="offcanvas-header bg-dark">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title text-white" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Menu</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body bg-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Project Overview</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Team</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="offcanvasNavbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Documentation
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Technical Documentation</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ethics & Responsibility</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Licensing & Contribution</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>



